# Dropbox duplicating files "too many files"

Tags: php, curl, zip, dropbox

I will go straight to the point,
i was thinking of using dropbox as a file sharing system for some files that i am distributing through my website. So after some research and some hours of reading the documentation, i am now able to upload, generate links and share my files from my PHP built website. So far so good.

Now lets go to the problem.

The files that i am uploading/distributing  are the same for every member with an exclusion of one file (license.txt) which needs to be different on every member.

So to solve this problem i came up with one idea, i will open the ZIP file through PHP and the core side of my server, add/replace the license.txt file, ZIP it again and upload it. Yeah that works like a charm but guess what? Its a 80mb file and takes more than 4 minutes to complete the whole process which is something i want to avoid.

So to make it much faster i came up with another idea. My idea was to distribute the files directly from the dropbox un-zipped by duplicating the root folder (of the APP). So the whole process was really simple, firstly an API call to duplicate the root folder (the one that was containing the files), then another one to upload only the edited license.txt file on the new duplicated folder and one last API call to generate the share link. It worked really well and much faster on my tests, but when i finalized my code and tried it live, it turned out to be a disaster since i got an error "too many files".

So my questions is, if there's any way to touch somehow remotely zipped files on dropbox. I saw that the browser can OPEN without problem any ZIP file and show all the contained folders.

Am i missing any possible solution? Any advice would be more than appreciated.

Comment: just buy some cheap s3 storage, why make life hard for your self.

Comment: The Dropbox API doesn't offer a way to remotely zip/unzip files, or operate on individual files inside zip files, but I'll pass this along as a feature request.